# HtmlWebpackPlugin doesn't pass pug variables to included pug file

Tags: variables, webpack, pug, html-webpack-plugin

I have a basic understanding of how `webpack` and `pug` can work together, using `HtmlWebpackPlugin` to generate a page with the bundled assets using the pug template.

I've created a very simple test project with two pug files: `head.pug` contains the stuff that goes in `<head>`, and `index.pug` is the rest. I created some variables in `index.pug` which I expect to use in `head.pug` by using `include head.pug`. Here is what they look like:

```
// head.pug //
title #{title}

if isProduction
    base(href='myurl.com/welcome/')

// index.pug //
- var isProduction = true
- var title = 'Testing'

doctype html
html
    head
        include head.pug
    body
        p My Site
```

If I use the `pug-cli` to compile `index.pug`, it creates the following `index.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing</title>
        <base href="myurl.com/welcome/">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>My Site</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Looks good. Now, if I use `webpack` to build my assets and generate `index.html`, it looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>My Site</p>
        <script src="/bundle6028aa4f7993fc1329ca.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the title wasn't defined, and isProduction is false, so `<base>` isn't inserted. What's going wrong? Here is my webpack config file:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/js/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle[contenthash].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.pug$/, loader: "pug-loader" },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(), 
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: '!!pug-loader!src/pug/index.pug',
      filename: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html')
    })
  ]
};
```

Comment: Should work. How do you call or render the pug file?

Comment: @kmgt you were right, it does work. However, that's using pug directly. If I use HtmlWebpackPlugin, it doesn't work. I rewrote the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Webpack rule for pug files with these loaders:

```
...
{
    test: /\.pug$/,
    use: [
        {
            loader: 'html-loader'
        },
        {
            loader: 'pug-html-loader'
        }
    ],
},
...
```

And maybe you can rid of `!!pug-loader!` for the plugins template property:

```
...
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: './src/pug/index.pug',
    filename: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html')
})
...
```

Probably you have to install the loaders via npm:

```
npm i html-loader pug-html-loader
```

Comment: This didn't really answer why pug-loader wasn't working, but this solution works, so I'll accept it. Thank you